# Elastic Search - Rolling Calculations

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a series of JSON documents like `{"type":"A", "value": 2}, {"type":"B"," value":3}, and {"type":"C","value":7}` and I feed that into elastic search.

Let's say I want to do one query to avg value all documents with `"type": "A"`

What is the difference between how elastic search calculates the count vs how let's say Mongo would?

Is Elastic search:

1. Automatically creating a "rolling count" for all those types and
   incrementing the something like "typeA_sum", "typeA_count" "typeA_avg" as new
   data is fed in? If so that would be sweet, because then it's not
   actually having to calculate anything.
2. Is it just creating an
   index over type and actually calculate the sum each time the query
   is ran?
3. Is it doing #2 in the background (i.e. precalculating)
   and just updating some cache value so when the query runs it has the
   result pretty quickly?

Answer (score 1):

It is closest to your #2, however the results are cached, so that if the results are useful in a subsequent query that will be very quick. There is no way Elasticsearch could know beforehand what query you are going to run, so #1 is impossible, and #3 would be wasteful.

However, for your example use case you probably do not need two queries, one would be enough. See for instance the [stats aggregation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-stats-aggregation.html) that will return count, min, max, average and sum. Combine that with a [terms aggregation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) (and perhaps a [missing aggregation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-missing-aggregation.html)) to group the documents on your `type` field, and you'll get count and average (and min, max, sum) for all types separately with a single query.

Comment: Thanks. For #1, I thought that we can tell Elastic Search that information. So based on your answer my next question is, why is this better than just using Mongo?

Comment: In this sense, I don't think it is "better" than Mongodb.